# integrate api to an existing Qt/qml project

Tags: qt, qml

it's my first time using Qt/qml and API , i am trying to add like prayer time to my project depend on country ... i watched many videos and QT doc about adding rest api but i still cound not get the good idea how to do this .

To inderstand what i want to do :

*i have API that i want to add
*i searched on youtube how to add a rest api on a project but it's totally different i should do in a Qt/qml project

Is there anyone could help?
(i really have searched on many Qt doc and on youtube and i still need to learn more )

Comment: First hit on a Google search for QML Rest API: https://www.qt.io/product/qt6/qml-book/ch13-networking-rest-api

Comment: Have you tried using `XMLHttpRequest` ?

Comment: @hyde can you explain to me the whole process , i have the api it's already set on github but i don't know to add it to my existing project , i searched on youtube but they do with other programming languages

Comment: I don't know about other programming languages, but I meant the standard JavaScript XMLHttpRequest. Try to use that from QML.

Answer (score 1):

To access rest API in qt or in any platform will boil down to three steps:

1. Setting up API credentials
2. Obtaining Authorization to make calls
3. Making calls to the API

For step 1. Setting up your api credentials. You will need to go to the website of the REST API you intent to use, then follow their steps to create a client key and application id, callback url etc.  Then you will need to save that information to be used in step 2.  Usually you can download a json or plist

For Step 2: Obtaining Authorization, you will need to use the QOAuthorizationCodeFlow.  You can see my answer to this question for an example with google api. [example qt oauthflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76030218/issue-connecting-google-api-to-qt-application/76219096#76219096)

For Step 3: Making a call to the REST API. You could use the last step in the google api sample above.  Or you can just put a network request together like this (you will need the qt network authorization module for this).  The URL in the example below would need to match the required url for the API you are using including keys and tokens etc.  You will need to make a class with .cpp and .h files.

in the .cpp file

```
nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
auto rep = nam->get(QUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json"));
            QEventLoop loop;
            connect(rep, &QNetworkReply::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
            loop.exec();
            QString currentByteArray = rep->readAll();
            qDebug() << "network reply google api connect step get info" << currentByteArray;
```

then in the .h file

```
private:
QNetworkAccessManager *nam = nullptr;
```

then the .pro file

```
QT += network networkauth
```

I hope this helps.

When I was learning about API's, I used postman to help me generate the API Urls prior to having to doing it in Qt.  Once I was comfortable with how to build the Url and was sure it worked, I then tried to make it all work within Qt.